# Redirect contact form on submit

Tags: forms, 8, redirection, emails

Using Drupal 8 and trying to get the contact form to redirect to the same page after submitting. By default it seem to redirect to the home page.

I have edited my themename.theme file

```
function themename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  //contact page form
  if ($form_id == 'contact_message_feedback_form') {
    $url = Url::fromRoute('contact.site_page');
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
  }
}
```

This throws a bunch of mysql errors. Like so:

```
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes: UPDATE {sessions} SET uid=:db_update_placeholder_0, hostname=:db_update_placeholder_1, session=:db_update_placeholder_2, timestamp=:db_update_placeholder_3 WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_update_placeholder_1] => ::1 [:db_update_placeholder_2] => _sf2_attributes|a:1:{s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:4:{s:1:"u";i:1454074283;s:1:"c";i:1452243053;s:1:"l";s:7:"2000000";s:1:"s";s:43:"dVseXv540u6wL5GZm_gs6fzuP9qtck-j5A5lexqnaQE";}authorize_page_title|O:48:"Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup":3:{s:9:"*string";s:14:"Update manager";s:12:"*arguments";a:0:{}s:10:"*options";a:0:{}}messages|a:1:{s:6:"status";a:2:{i:0;O:25:"Drupal\Core\Render\Markup":1:{s:9:"*string";s:1020035:"<script class="-kint-js">(function(){if("undefined"===typeof kintInitialized){kintInitialized=1;var e=[],f=-1,g=function(b){var a=window in Drupal\Core\Session\SessionHandler->write() (line 89 of /Users/timmcdonald/Code/waypoint/v3/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php).
```

and other errors.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You cannot set it in the form itself. You have to use a submit function for that. Although altering forms works in themes this example should totally be in a module and not in theme.

Comment: You might be interested to know that the Contact Storage module provides custom redirects on submission. Although be aware of this issue with it: drupal.org/node/2629630

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I ended up doing in a custom module if anyone else needs to do this

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  //contact page form
  if ($form_id == 'contact_message_feedback_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_module_contact_submit';
    dpm($form['actions']['submit']);
  }

}

function custom_module_contact_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    drupal_set_message('we sent a form woohoo');
    $url = Url::fromRoute('contact.site_page');
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: `dpm` will cause an error unless the `devel` module is enabled. I also left out `$form_id` from the parameter list since Drupal complained of a missing third argument.

Comment: FYI for latecomers to this answer - drupal_set_message has been replaced by Messenger. See here https://www.drupal.org/node/2774931

Answer (score 4):

And to make it even better

```
/**
 * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function minimal_form_contact_message_contact_me_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'minimal_contact_submit';
}

/**
 * Contact form submit handler
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 */
function minimal_contact_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('we sent a form woohoo');
  // From URL to URL object
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/node/16');
  $form_state->setRedirect('contact.site_page');
}
```

I found it useful, so maybe other people could find it useful too

Comment: very useful fromUserInput

Comment: I ended up using `$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => '16']);` to get the dynamic route

Comment: wolffer-east answer is the correct one.
In Cifren example, where is $url used?

Answer (score 1):

Tim's solution will also work from a theme.

In this case the theme is called 'minimal', and the code below is in the minimal.theme file. I'm calling hook_form_FORM_ID_alter on a form with ID: contact_message_contact_me

Also note the signature on the submit handler, as well as the direct call to redirect with the default site-wide route for the contact form (my form above is set to the default). You don't need to build the Url first.

```
/**
 * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function minimal_form_contact_message_contact_me_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'minimal_contact_submit';
}

/**
 * Contact form submit handler
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 */
function minimal_contact_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('contact.site_page');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to the same page, whatever it is (if you use contact block module for instance), you can use this in your submit callback:

```
$form_state->setRedirectUrl(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRouteMatch(\Drupal::routeMatch()));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom module for my form. In the submit function, I did not set a redirect URL, in which the submit function will not redirect to any page, and therefore show the form page again. This because the form submits to the same page the form is on.

Edit: After I posted this answer I noted that you asked about the Drupal contact form. So naturally this answer is wrong. Always read the brief twice and then two more times.

```
<?php
/**
 * File: ContactForm.php
 */

namespace Drupal\module_name\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

class ContactForm extends FormBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'module_name_contact_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Form 
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Form validation
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message('Form submitted');
    }
}
```